# Convert data format in R

Tags: r

I have a data set, dat, which was got from a model run.

The head of the dataset looks like this:

```
[[1]]

[1] -1

[[2]]

[2] -2

[[3]]

[3] -1

[[4]]

[4] 0

[[5]]

[5] -6

[[6]]

[6] -7
```

How can I convert dat to a simple data frame with a single column like this

```
-1
-2
-1
0
-6
-7
```

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `unlist` function. For example:

```
unlist(list(1,2,3,4,5))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

And you can turn it into a column by `cbind`ing the results

```
a = unlist(list(1,2,3,4,5))
> cbind(a)
     a
[1,] 1
[2,] 2
[3,] 3
[4,] 4
[5,] 5
```

Comment: Note that `cbind(a)` yields a matrix *not* a data frame. Wrap a `data.frame()` around it.

Answer (score 2):

You have something like this:

```
L <- as.list(1:10)
L
```

So, one way is to:

```
> data.frame(name = t(data.frame(L)))
     name
X1L     1
X2L     2
X3L     3
X4L     4
X5L     5
X6L     6
X7L     7
X8L     8
X9L     9
X10L   10
```

Replace `name` with whatever you want the name of the variable to be.

Comment: I guess I could use dat2<-as.matrix(dat) and dat3<-as.data.frame(dat2)